# How to use the value of a variable that is declared as an array ( ending with '[ ]' )?

Tags: php, arrays, variables

```
<?php $postid[] = get_the_ID(); // capture the id (a number) ?>
```

Now If I echo `$postid` I just get: **Array**

and when I do the following:

```
<?php
    $default = array(
        'posts_per_page' => $postid
    );
?>
```

I don't get anything either.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When working with arrays in PHP, you can use the following to assign an array to a variable :

```
// initalize empty array
$a = array();
var_dump($a);
```

*(The `array()` could be non-empty, of course)*

Or you can use the following syntax, without the indexes :

```
// push items at the end of the array
$a[] = 10;
$a[] = 20;
var_dump($a);
```

And, finally, you can set an item at a key of your choice :

```
// put an item at a given index
$a['test'] = 'plop';
var_dump($a);
```

For more informations, see the [**Arrays** sections of the manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php).

Doing so, thanks to the three [**`var_dump()`**][2] calls, I'll get :

```
array
  empty

array
  0 => int 10
  1 => int 20

array
  0 => int 10
  1 => int 20
  'test' => string 'plop' (length=4)
```

Note : many use [**`print_r()`**](http://fr.php.net/print_r) instead of **`var_dump()`** -- I tend to prefer **`var_dump()`**, which displays more informations, especially when the [**Xdebug extension**](http://xdebug.org/) is installed.

But note that, in any case, calling [**`echo`**][5] on an array itself :

```
echo $a;
```

Will get nothing else as output than :

```
Array
```

Which is not quite useful ;-)

Still, you can display the value of a single item of that array :

echo $a['test'];

Which, in this case, would get you this output :

```
plop
```

Basically : `echo` is not what you should use when you want to display an array :

- Either use `var_dump()` if you want to inspect an array for debugging purposes,
- or loop over the array with [`foreach`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php), displaying each item with echo

  - Note : you might have to do some recursion, to inspect sub-arrays ;-)